# Stop a function when link is clicked. JQuery

Tags: jquery, function, gallery, slideshow

I have a slideshow named `rotatePics()`that begins on pageload. I also have a number of `li`'s that when clicked, will get the `rel` value of that `li`. The `rel`'s of the `li`'s match up with the `id`'s of the preloaded slideshow images. So when one is clicked, I want to stop the current slideshow function named rotatePics and restart it but parsing a new integer.

Currently what is happening, is that I am able to run the NEW slideshow function, but not replace the slideshow function that runs when the page loads.

I need to stop `rotatePics()` and restart it with the variable `number` with only the latter function running.

```
$('a.main-img').click(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var clickedLi = $(this).closest('li').attr('rel');

    var number = parseInt(clickedLi);

    rotatePics(number);

});
```

This is the code for the `rotatePics()` function

```
    function rotatePics(currentPhoto){

    var numberOfPhotos = $('#banner-holder img').length;

    currentPhoto = currentPhoto % numberOfPhotos;

    $('#banner-holder img').eq(currentPhoto).fadeOut(function (){
        $('#banner-holder img').each(function (i)
        {
            $(this).css('zIndex', ((numberOfPhotos - i) + currentPhoto) % numberOfPhotos);
        });

        $(this).show();

        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            rotatePics(++currentPhoto); 
        }, 1000);
    });
};
```

I am also aware that the modulus section changes the integer, This was originally just a rolling slideshow and without the option to select new images.

Comment: Why not use `data-id` instead of abusing `rel` for it?

Comment: Can you please post the code for the `rotatePics()` function?  That would be helpful.

Comment: rels work, used them in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your timeout as follows:

```
var rotatePicsTimer;
function rotatePics(currentPhoto){ 

    var numberOfPhotos = $('#banner-holder img').length; 

    currentPhoto = currentPhoto % numberOfPhotos; 

    $('#banner-holder img').eq(currentPhoto).fadeOut(function (){ 
        $('#banner-holder img').each(function (i) 
        { 
            $(this).css('zIndex', ((numberOfPhotos - i) + currentPhoto) % numberOfPhotos); 
        }); 

        $(this).show(); 

        rotatePicsTimer = setTimeout(function () 
        { 
            rotatePics(++currentPhoto);  
        }, 1000); 
    }); 
};

$('a.main-img').click(function (e)   
{   
    e.preventDefault();   

    var clickedLi = $(this).closest('li').attr('rel');   

    var number = parseInt(clickedLi);   

    clearTimeout(rotatePicsTimer);
    rotatePics(number);
});
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. Thankyou so much. Only slight issue I have is that it doesnt fadeIn, but I will sort this. many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to assign the return value of `setTimeout` to a variable and then call `clearTimeout`.

```
var timerID;

// ...

timerID = setTimeout(function ()
{
    rotatePics(++currentPhoto); 
}, 1000);

// ...

clearTimeout(timerID);
```